# Makebst option vol-2bf does nothing

Tags: bibtex, natbib, custom-bib

Can somebody explain to me why using option `vol-2bf` does not affect my `.bst` file? It would expect it to have `bolden` between lines 1157 and 1158, but it does not. Putting `bolden` there makes my `.bst` file work as expected.

.dbj file: https://gist.github.com/joelfrederico/f024accadf3d9750c247e2bef02eabc6#file-custom2-dbj

.bst file:
https://gist.github.com/joelfrederico/f024accadf3d9750c247e2bef02eabc6#file-custom2-bst

Comment: You are more likely to get help if you provide a complete minimal example people can test here rather than posting external links. Note that questions should remain meaningful which means they should not essentially depend on the content of other sites.

Comment: That is not possible for the .bst file- it's generated code. The .dbj may also not be possible, but I definitely don't have time to trim it down now.

Comment: Why do you ask for the volume and number to be in bold and then ask for the volume but not the number to be used at all?

Comment: Was really just a question, but OK. Glad it helped and, since it helped, I can hazard a guess as to why ... :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note:

```
%>>TECHNICAL REPORT NUMBER:
%<<JOURNAL VOLUME:
%   %: (def) Volume plain as vol(num)
% vol-it,%: Volume italic as {\em vol}(num)
% vol-bf,%: Volume bold as {\bf vol}(num)
  vol-2bf,%: Volume and number bold as {\bf vol(num)}
%------\ans=d(==vol-2bf)-------
%>>JOURNAL VOLUME:
```

So the setting requests that the volume and number be formatted as `<vol>(num>)` in bold.

But then we have:

```
%<<JOURNAL VOL AND NUMBER:
%   %: (def) Journal vol(num) as 34(2)
% vnum-sp,%: Journal vol (num) as 34 (2)
% vnum-cm,%: Journal vol, num as 34, 2
% vnum-nr,%: Journal vol, no. num as 34, no. 2
% vnum-h,%: Journal vol, \# number as 34, \#2
% vnum-b,%: Journal vol number as 34 2
  vnum-x,%: Journal vol, without number as 34
%------\ans=x(==vnum-x)-------
```

So the request is that the volume be set without the number at all.

I simply asked why these settings were chosen in combination.

If this solved the problem, as the OP said, I assume it is because the `vol-2bf` applies bold to the volume-number combo *if and when that is used*. But since that combo is never used, in accordance with `vnum-x`, it is never applied.

I imagine that `vol-bf` might be a better choice with `vnum-x` or that `vnum-sp`, say, might be a better option with `vol-2bf`.